# How do I search for an element using for loop once the arrays have been arranged?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

after arranging my arrays in alphabetical order I need to add a for   loop action to search for a specific element in one of the arrays.

In this case I need to search for "Rogers. Steve". How should I     proceed?

Thank you in advance for all the help!

I've tried several examples but I can't get it right...

```
String[] arrayString=new String[]{
 "Administrator",
 "Vale.Vicky",
 "Lane.Lois",
 "Kent.Clark",
 "Wayne.Bruce",
 "Parker.Peter",
 "Rogers.Steve",
 "Luther.Lex",
 "Osborn.Harry",
 "Tony.Stark"};
String searchString="Rogers.Steve";

//Loop until the length of the array
//Print the index of the string on an array
System.out.println("Rogers.Steve");
```

My class.

```
package helloworldjavabook;

public class HelloWorldjavabook {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] user = {"Administrator", "Vale.Vicky", "Lane.Lois", "Kent.Clark", "Wayne.Bruce",
      "Parker.Peter", "Rogers.Steve", "Luther.Lex", " Osborn.Harry", "Tony.Stark"};
    orderedGuests(user);
    String[] password = {"PASSWORD1", "ILOVEBRUCE", "ILOVECLARK", "  ILOVELOIS", "IAMGOTHAM", "IAMSPECTACULAR",
      "IAMAMERICA", "IRUNLEXCORP", "IAMGREENGOBLIN", "  IAMINVINCIBLE"};
    orderedGuests(password);
    String id[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    orderedGuests(id);
  }

  private static void orderedGuests(String[] hotel) {
    Arrays.sort(hotel);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hotel));
  }

}
```

Comment: That's quite easy  Arrays.asList(user).indexOf("Rogers.Steve");

Comment: Thank you so much ! I understand the format better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void search() {
    String[] arrayString = new String[]{
      "Administrator",
      "Vale.Vicky",
      "Lane.Lois",
      "Kent.Clark",
      "Wayne.Bruce",
      "Parker.Peter",
      "Rogers.Steve",
      "Luther.Lex",
      "Osborn.Harry",
      "Tony.Stark"};
    String searchString = "Rogers.Steve";

    Arrays.sort(arrayString);
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arrayString, searchString));
}
```

The key piece of this is

```
Arrays.binarySearch(arrayString, searchString)
```

Comment: Your welcome.  Don't forget to upvote the answer and accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
String[] arrayString=new String[]{
 "Administrator",
 "Vale.Vicky",
 "Lane.Lois",
 "Kent.Clark",
 "Wayne.Bruce",
 "Parker.Peter",
 "Rogers.Steve",
 "Luther.Lex",
 "Osborn.Harry",
 "Tony.Stark"};
String searchString="Rogers.Steve";

int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++) { 
    if(arrayString[i] == searchString ){
        position = i;
    }
}
if( position > 0 ){
    System.out.println("Position: " + position); 
} else {
    System.out.println(searchString + " not found" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a better idea on how to proceed.